# PhpStorm Как импортировать БД

Tags: phpstorm

Как в PhpStorm импортировать локальную базу данных в проект ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 -> Я создал пустую базу, а теперь, сюда хочу залить дамб базы с сервера

Comment: через mysql workbench делайте лучше.

Comment: Я пока что OpenServer пользую, но ведь должна быть возможность